# visual studio 2013 checkout not working

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have a web project on Team Foundation Server, but when I go to checkout of the files, I do not see them in the solution explorer locally. They are on my computer, but not in the Solution Explorer, and therefore I can't use the browser link to view them.

In the Solution Explorer I have one `web.config` file, but no html file that I want. In the team explorer I have 3 `web.config` files. I'm kinda confused as to how my directory structure should look. If I open the html file from the team explorer, I'm getting a `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`, which seems appropriate since it is not local.

Any help is great!

Answer (score 0):

So I found out why my local file structure did not match the team foundation server file structure.  I clicked on "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer, and a bunch of files for some annoying unknown reason were greyed out, including the html file that I was trying to work with. Once I clicked on "Include in Project" it no longer was greyed out and I can open it using browser link and check-in and checkout without any problems.